# Python: Check if index in list a = input = index in list b

Tags: python, sequence

What I want to happen:

Python chooses a random question from a list and prompts user input, then checks if the index value for the answer input (so `a1` = `0`) matches the index for chosen question.

Here's an example:

```
questionsList = [q1,q2]
answersList = [a1,a2]
```

where `a1` is the answer to `q1`, `a2` to `q2` and so on.

```
answer = input(random.choice(questionsList))
```

> if q1 was picked and user input == a1: stuff happens
>
> else: other stuff happens

I don't know how to tell the computer to remember which question was picked and check if that question's index value equals the answer's index value.

Answer (score 1):

Zip them together and pick a pair instead.

```
pairList = zip(questionsList, answersList)
pair = random.choice(pairlist)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest instead of keeping two different lists, you can keep a single list of tuples, where the first element of the tuple would be the question, and the second element of the tuple would be the answer. And then make `random.choice()` pick from that list of tuples, and then ask the question (first element of the chosen tuple) to user, and compare the answer given by user against the answer chosen (second element of the chosen tuple). Example -

```
import random
q_and_a = [('q1','a1'),('q2','a2'),('q3','a3')]
ques_chosen, ans_chosen = random.choice(q_and_a)
#Use ques_chosen as the chosen question
#Use ans_chosen as the chosen answer.
```

If you want to programmatically create this tuple list from two lists, you can use the `built-in` function `zip()`. Example -

```
q_and_a = zip(questionsList, answersList) #You would need `list(zip(..))` for Python 3.x
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you find...

```
# random int beetwen your questionsList bounds
random_question = random.randint(0, len(questionsList))

# Show questions, and read user's answer  
answer = input(questionsList[random_questions]))

# If user's answer is the same that the answer stored in list...
if answer == answerList[random_questions] :

    # STUFF HAPPENS

# else, if answer is bad...
else:

    # OTHER STUFF HAPPENS
```